# How to enable/view hidden tabs in magento admin panel?

Tags: magento, ssl

I need to enable the SSL certificate through my magento admin panel. The SSL certificate is already installed on the server. Some of the tabs in configuration menu (web, currency etc) are hidden or disabled by the previous website developer. I cannot see the 'WEB' option under 'GENERAL' tab in the configuration menu. Could anyone help me please how to enable the hidden tabs?

Comment: go to the system > configuration and In left side navigation set Current Configuration Scope: as Default config and then go to your relevant tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have database access, you can change the role of current user in table `admin_role` in row `role_type`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, problem solved. I also did some changes in admin_rule table as there were few permissions denied there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to view the web tab inside general it may be due to several reasons
1) you are login not as admin in magento admin section.
2) The tab must be disable programmatically from core.

Hope it helps you

THanks,